# Adding and dividing values between tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL and wanted to learn it by making a leaderboard from a game I play.

I have a function where I want to get an accurate total average for all seasons.

I have successfully imported my parsed data that into the database.

I have a table like this for every season

```
season1
------------------------
| name | score | games |
------------------------
| joe  | 254   |   25  |
| bob  | 200   |   32  |
| jim  | 365   |   65  |
------------------------
```

I need to run a function like this

```
((S1.games*S1.score)+(S2.games*S2.score)+(S3.games*S3.score)+(S4.games*S4.score))

/

((S1.games)+(S2.games)+(S3.games)+(S4.games))
```

and have it total this based on pilots name

For the life of me I can not figure out how to do complex functions between tables.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why do you have a table per season? There's your problem. You should have a singular table with a `season` column you can use for grouping purposes.

Comment: 1) what have you tried? 2) You're probably looking for some form of join (Most likely a inner join)

Comment: @tadman seasons are pulled monthly with a parse from a website. Would it be better to group it into a single table?

Comment: @SethMcClaine I thought about this but I couldnt find a join method that supported different IDs that arent always the same between tables. Some season a player pays again while other times they don't or new players join.

Comment: Absolutely. This is one of the fundamental principles behind relational database schema design: You want the table names to be largely irrelevant, and you want all the data of one particular kind to be in one table. It makes queries like this *significantly* easier.

Comment: @tadman Good information. Thanks. The problem is, I am unsure how to import data into the same table and match pilot names.

Comment: What does `games*score` represent here? That's an odd factor to see being used. In any case, a single table will present a far, far simpler solution since you can use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @tadman games multiplied by score. A union all however would not work in this example.

Comment: A UNION would work fine. It will simply be a lot less efficient than working off a single table.

Comment: @Strawberry how would you multiply different columns in a table before adding it to another table in a union though?

Comment: Not 'before'. 'After'.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something as simple as

```
SELECT S1.name, ((S1.games*S1.score)+(S2.games*S2.score)+(S3.games*S3.score)+(S4.games*S4.score)) / ((S1.games)+(S2.games)+(S3.games)+(S4.games)) as TOTAL 
FROM Season1 as S1, Season2 as S2, Season3 as S3, Season4 as S4 group by S1.name;
```

This isn't very efficient though.

Comment: This smashes all the scores together for all teams. This requires an extremely ugly `JOIN` between all four tables to link them up correctly.

Comment: @SethMcClaine thanks for the help and your time. However, I get 

     Column 'Name' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: You just need to say which name you want table you want name to be pulled from, so just add S1 infront of name where name is used (example updated)

Answer (score 0):

```
Ok, try this one.

SELECT S1.name, ((S1.games*S1.score)+(S2.games*S2.score)+(S3.games*S3.score)+(S4.games*S4.score)) / ((S1.games)+(S2.games)+(S3.games)+(S4.games)) as TOTAL 
FROM
  (SELECT 
    S1.name as name, 
    S1.games as S1Games, 
    S1.score as S1Score,
    S2.games as S2Games, 
    S2.score as S2Score,
    S3.games as S3Games, 
    S3.score as S3Score,
    S4.games as S4Games, 
    S4.score as S4Score
  FROM Season1 as S1 
  JOIN Season2 as S2 ON S1.name = S2.name
  JOIN Season3 as S3 ON S1.name = S3.name
  JOIN Season4 as S3 ON s1.name = S4.name)
GROUP BY S1.name
```

Comment: Error  #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: You probably have to do an alias "as S1" try the updated example